# C++ equivalent of 'pack' in Perl

Tags: c++, perl, pack

How do I write C++ code that does what the [pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) `-N` option does in Perl?

I want to convert an integer variable to some binary form such that the [unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) -N option on it gives back the integer variable.

My integer variable name is timestamp.

I found that it is related to htonl, but still htonl(timestamp) does not give the binary form.

Comment: pack converts the number to a string, not binary form, right? See `itoa` or `std::to_string`

Comment: Do you want to *pack* it in C++ and *unpack* in perl (or vice-versa)? Just asking, since in C++ there is no *binary* form in C++. Integers are just binary values, as opposed to Perl where they might be represented as strings...

Comment: do you have some code of the conversions? would make things easier.

Comment: @deviantfan: `pack` converts to a sequence of bytes, which may or may not be character-like.  So it depends how exactly `pack` and `unpack` are being used...

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a library, `libpack`, similar to Perl's `pack` function. It's a C library so it would be quite usable from C++ as well:

```
FILE *f;
fpack(f, "u32> u32>", value_a, value_b);
```

A `u32 >` specifies an unsigned 32-bit integer in big-endian format; i.e. equivalent to Perl's `N` format to `pack()`.

http://www.leonerd.org.uk/code/libpack/

Answer (score 1):

It takes 4 bytes and forms a 32-bit int as follows:

```
uint32_t n;
n = buf[0] << 24
  | buf[1] << 16
  | buf[2] <<  8
  | buf[3] <<  0;
```

For example,

```
uint32_t n;
unsigned char buf[4];
size_t bytes_read = fread(buf, 1, 4, stream);
if (bytes_read < 4) {
   if (ferror(stream)) {
      // Error
      // ...
   }
   else if (feof(stream)) {
      // Premature EOF
      // ...
   }
}
else {
   n = buf[0] << 24
     | buf[1] << 16
     | buf[2] <<  8
     | buf[3] <<  0;
}
```